# How to Search If UITabelviewcell as 2 arrays in iOS swift4?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have two arrays like `names = ["Gopal","Harish","Krishna","Ramu"]` and `numbers = ["468648","586385","5868544","354333"]`. I am displaying these 2 arrays in `UItableViewCell`. But Whenever I am searching by names, Its searching only name not by respective number. How to filter name with respective number in iOS swift

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    filtered = names.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
        let tmp: NSString = text
        let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })
    if(filtered.count == 0){
        searchActive = false;
    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

In View did load :

```
    for i in nameArr

    {

        for j in numberArr

        {
            models = [
                Contact(name:i, number:j)
            ]


        }
    }
```

Comment: You are saying `filtered = names.filter`. So you are not searching the other array, whatever it is called (`numbers` perhaps?). So naturally you are not finding. Search and you will find.

Comment: Use a struct and store both `name` and `number` in it and then filter the array of that struct by `name`.

Comment: @Rakesha Shastri : Could you please add some relevant code.

Comment: @iosios you should read the [Swift Programming Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/).

Comment: @Rakesha Shastri : I am defining name and number arrays like that in viewdidload. Is it right procedure. Actually I am following this link: https://www.journaldev.com/14126/ios-uisearchcontroller-uitableview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to map each name to number in in contact, you should probably use one for loop.

Try printing the Contact instances at the end of the viewDidLoad()
The model will have 16 items in its array.

If you just want 4 items in array,

```
class PhoneBook : NSViewController {

    struct Contact {
       let name: String
       let number: String
    }

    let names = ["Gopal","Harish","Krishna","Ramu"]
    let numbers = ["468648","586385","5868544","354333"]

    override func loadView() {
        var model: [Contact] = []
        for index in 0..<names.count
        {
            model.append(Contact(name: names[index], number: numbers[index]))
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Good solution. Also, you can use the filter (high order function) function to filter out data. Easy and quick solution.

Comment: @ mouseymaniiac: Its working like a charm.ThankYou So much for your help.I accepted answer.